# Append a query string to the end of every URL

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, cache

I'm trying to append a query string to the end of every URL for logged in users for cache busting purposes. Here is the code I have but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```php
function add_admin_qs($url){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return add_query_arg('nocfcache', 'true', $url);
    }
}
    
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    add_filter( 'home_url', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'post_link', 'add_admin_qs', 10, 1);
    add_filter( 'page_link', 'add_admin_qs', 10, 1);
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'add_admin_qs', 10, 1);
    add_filter( 'category_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'tag_link', 'add_admin_qs', 10, 1);
    add_filter( 'author_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'day_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'month_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'year_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I used the wrong type of quote marks. You cannot see it in my first post because apparently they were changed when I pasted in the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
function add_admin_qs($url){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return add_query_arg('nocfcache', 'true', $url);
    }
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function(){   
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    add_filter( 'home_url', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'post_link', 'add_admin_qs', 10, 1);
    add_filter( 'page_link', 'add_admin_qs', 10, 1);
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'add_admin_qs', 10, 1);
    add_filter( 'category_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'tag_link', 'add_admin_qs', 10, 1);
    add_filter( 'author_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'day_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'month_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
    add_filter( 'year_link', 'add_admin_qs', 11, 1);
}
});
```

I think the main problem is you're loading your code at the WP load and maybe before you're really logged in for WP.

Comment: See my answer above.